# Creating a numpy array from a vector by removing one item at a time

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list b of elements of size n.
I want to create a 2D numpy array of size (n-1,n) from this list such that i-th row is the elements of b without the i-th term.

For example, if

```
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

The numpy array will be,

```
A = np.array( [[2,3,4],
               [1,3,4],
               [1,2,4],
               [1,2,3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** One approach with `masking` -

```
n = len(b)
b2D = np.broadcast_to(b, (n,n)) # or np.repeat(b[None],n,axis=0)
out = b2D[~np.eye(n, dtype=bool)].reshape(n,-1)
```

**Approach #2 :** With focus on performance and memory efficiency, another with [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
n = len(b)
b_ext = np.r_[b[1:],b[:-1]]
s = b_ext.strides[0]
out = strided(b_ext, shape=(n-1,n), strides=(s,s)).reshape(n,-1)
```